# Help reading proof that $\text{Var}\left( \frac{X}{\sigma_X}+\frac{Y}{\sigma_Y} \right) =2[1 + \rho(X,Y)]$

Tags: probability-theory

According to my textbook's discussion on covariance and correlation,

> It can be shown that $-1 \le \ \rho (X,Y) \le \ 1$

where $\rho(X,Y)= \large \frac{\text{Cov(X,Y)}}{\left (\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)\right)^{1/2}} $

The proof goes as follows
$$\begin{align}
&0 \le \text{Var}\left( \frac{X}{\sigma_X}+\frac{Y}{\sigma_Y} \right) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{X}{\sigma_X} \right) + \text{Var}\left( \frac{Y}{\sigma_Y} \right) + 2\text{Cov}\left (\frac{X}{\sigma_X},\frac{Y}{\sigma_Y} \right)  \\
&=2[1 + \rho(X,Y)]
\end{align}$$

It is the second, final line that I do not follow. What identities or algebraic manipulations are used to make the second line follow from the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a consequence of the fact that
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(aX,bY)=ab\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)
$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ (this is easily derived using the definition of covariance). From this also follows that
$$
\mathrm{Var}(aX)=a^2\mathrm{Var}(X),
$$
since $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$. Use these identities with $a=\frac{1}{\sigma_X}$ and $b=\frac{1}{\sigma_Y}$.

Comment: Using these facts I have
$
\text{Var}\left( \frac{X}{\sigma_X}+\frac{Y}{\sigma_Y} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_X^2} \right) \text{Var}(X) +  \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_Y^2}\right)\text{Var}(Y)  + \large \frac{2}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} \normalsize \text{Cov}\left (X, Y \right) $

what next?

Comment: Use what $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ is defined to be.

Comment: $\sigma_X^2 = \text{Var}(X)$, $\sigma_Y^2 = \text{Var}(Y)$, so 

$\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_X^2} \right) \text{Var}(X) +  \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_Y^2}\right)\text{Var}(Y)  + \large \frac{2}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} \normalsize \text{Cov}\left (X, Y \right) = 1 + 1 + 2 \large \frac{\text{Cov}\left (X, Y \right)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} \normalsize = 2(1 + \rho(X,Y)) $

Comment: Indeed @FoF. ${}$